How to use Notification "MediaStyle" on MAUI?
Regarding this simple Android Developper Documentation this is the way to use "Action" buttons in a "Media Style" :
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/expanded?hl=en#media-style
And I remember that was the solution I used in my Xamarin app version.
Unfortunately, in MAUI, there isn't MediaStyleNotificationHelper.
However, NotificationCompat.Builder.SetStyle() seems to wait a NotificationCompat.Style and NotificationCompat seems to have static property inherited from NotificationCompat.Style :

BigTextStyle
CallStyle
InboxStyle
MessagingStyle
DecoratedCustomViewStyle

But no MediaStyle.
Is there a way to use MediaStyle in MAUI ?
I tried "F1" on SetStyle from Visual Studio 2022, but I found a "Oups!" page without content...

Meanwhile I'm using this solution : https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/build-notification#Actions . But the action button is hide when notification is in "compact" mode so user must to "expand" it to watch the action button... it's not very user-friendly to stop a media.

Well if you want to use MediaStyleNotificationHelper.MediaStyle in Maui, you may first install the Xamarin.AndroidX.Media3.Session NuGet,  which provides .NET for Android bindings for the Java library androidx.media3:media3-session.
In the project, you may using Conditional compilation to import,
#if ANDROID
    using AndroidX.Media3.Session;
#endif

Then you have access to MediaStyleNotificationHelper.MediaStyle
